# Performing a Distance Matrix based on specific attributes

Tags: qgis

I have two point layers with a field called names (A1, A2, A3....) in both layers. I want to perform a distance matrix for those points, but just only for those with the same attribute 'name'. If  I run the tool distance matrix it takes too much time due to the high amount of data.

Edit: I did some work around by creating connecting lines and then calculate the length, but maybe there is a smarter solution.

[image]

Comment: Do a database join first?

Comment: `name` attribute is unique for two layers?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, yes they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script helps. Run it in QGIS Python Editor.

```
field = "name"

# change layer name
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer1_name")[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer2_name")[0]

for feat1 in layer1.getFeatures():
    name = feat1[field]    

    for feat2 in layer2.getFeatures(f"{field} = '{name}'"):
        d = feat1.geometry().distance(feat2.geometry())    
        print(f"{name}: {d}")
```